# Why was the Cup Winner's Cup abandoned?

Tags: football, history, uefa

Don't know if many people remember watching European football back then but I always enjoyed the Cup Winner's Cup. I was wondering why UEFA decided to get rid of the competition and effectively merge it with the UEFA cup? Was it played on the same night as the UEFA cup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Cup_Winners%27_Cup):

> After the establishment of the UEFA Champions League (formerly called the European Champion Clubs' Cup) in the early 1990s, the standing and prestige of the Cup Winners' Cup began to decline. With the expansion of the Champions League in 1997 to allow more than one team from the highest-ranked member associations to enter, the CWC began to look noticeably inferior.

Basically the same reason why UEFA abandoned [Intertoto Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertoto_Cup) and [UEFA Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Cup). It was old, not interesting anymore and needed improvement - that's where Champion's League came in.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any sources to back me up, but a fair assumption is that the domestic cups have been relatively "uncontested" in many countries. The priority for most top teams have always been the domestic leauge alongside the UEFAcup/Champions League.